# My bluetooth is acting weird, can't connect or find any device

Tags: 14.04, drivers, mouse, bluetooth, broadcom

I am new to the Ubuntu world. I've just installed newest version of Ubuntu, but I have one, very big problem. The thing is I can't connect to any bluetooth device, my phone doesn't see the notebook, even though it says it's on, also the "visible" option in Ubuntu is on. I also can't connect to my Microsoft Sculpt Comfort Mouse, it's not listed in the system, but phone sees it. The notebook model is Asus R556L.
lsusb output:

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
>
> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card
>
> Reader Controller
>
> Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp.
>
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b483 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
>
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

uname -r output:

> 3.19.0-30-generic

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 output:

> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]:
>
> Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
> Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:6675]
>
> Kernel driver in use: wl

Comment: Your bluetooth is `04ca:2006 Lite-On Technology Corp.`

Comment: So there's no legal way for me to use bluetooth in Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes there is a legal way ti use your bluetooth in Ubuntu. But it is illegal for me to give you the firmware. That is weird, but true. So you can convert the file yourself according to the instruction.

Comment: Aww, okay, thanks for your time then. I am going to try this solution out and let you know if it works :) Thanks

Comment: I am sure it works. But be careful with commands.

Comment: And you need to search for YOUR device that is 04ca:2006.

Comment: Okay, noticed that already ;)

Comment: Okay, it worked man, you are great. Thank you very much :)